# Cannot read the dumped JSON file back Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load a JSON file of mine which I have created from copying content from another JSON file. But I keep on getting the Error `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)` when I try to read JSON data from the file in which I copied all the data, My JSON  data is of the Format

```
{
    "server": {
        "ipaddress": "IP_Sample",
        "name": "name_Sample",
        "type": "type_Sample",
        "label": "label_Sample",
        "keyword": "kwd_Sample",
        "uid": "uid_Sample",
        "start_time": "start_Sample",
        "stop_time": "stop_Sample"
    }
}
```

And my load and write methods are

```
def load(self, filename):
    inputfile = open(filename,'r')
    self.data = json.loads(inputfile.read())
    print (self.data)
    inputfile.close()
    return

def write(self, filename):
    file = open(filename, "w")
    tempObject = self.data
    print type(tempObject)
    #json.dump(filename, self.data)
    print self.data["server"]
    print >> file, self.data
    file.close()
    return
```

I cannot figure out where I am going wrong, can anybody help me with that..

Comment: You need to post the error you are receiving.

Comment: I don't know what "the Error" is but your JSON is incorrect, fix this line: `"stop_time": "stop_Sample",` remove the `,`

Comment: Edited to make the data valid JSON and also list the error

Answer (score 3):

To save and load JSON to and from a file, use an open file object. Your code indicates you tried to save the filename to `self.data`, which is not a fileobject...

The following code works:

```
def write(self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as output:
        json.dump(self.data, output)

def load(self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as input:
        self.data = json.load(input)
```

I use the open files as context managers, to ensure they are closed when done reading or writing.

Your other attempt, `print >> file, self.data`, simply prints the *python representation* to the file, not JSON:

```
>>> print example
{u'server': {u'uid': u'uid_Sample', u'keyword': u'kwd_Sample', u'ipaddress': u'IP_Sample', u'start_time': u'start_Sample', u'label': u'label_Sample', u'stop_time': u'stop_Sample', u'type': u'type_Sample', u'name': u'name_Sample'}}
```

which, when read back from the file would give the error message you indicated:

```
>>> json.loads("{u'server': {u'uid': u'uid_Sample', u'keyword': u'kwd_Sample', u'ipaddress': u'IP_Sample', u'start_time': u'start_Sample', u'label': u'label_Sample', u'stop_time': u'stop_Sample', u'type': u'type_Sample', u'name': u'name_Sample'}}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 336, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self._scanner.iterscan(s, **kw).next()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 171, in JSONObject
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting property name", s, end))
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

You'd have to print the `json.dumps()` output instead:

```
>>> print json.dumps(example)
'{"server": {"uid": "uid_Sample", "keyword": "kwd_Sample", "ipaddress": "IP_Sample", "start_time": "start_Sample", "label": "label_Sample", "stop_time": "stop_Sample", "type": "type_Sample", "name": "name_Sample"}}'
```